Miller-Rabin primality test and random
Miller-Rabin primality test need random choosing number in each round. Time of random() is negligible compared to time of round ?
Problem is, how to generate big random numbers? Maybe best would be using fast hardware generator? What pseudorandom generator is good for test large numbers? Mersenne Twister generating 32 bit value? Maybe yes, because cycle length $2^{19937}$ is even much bigger than RSA numbers about $2^{3072}$
Second question: seed must have thousands of random bits?

The more randomness comes from outside , the better. At least if you actually want to use your numbers for RSA. Otherwise attacks might be possible.
